# Returning only the MAX for each grouping after GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to display only the highest values by each ward number after aggregating by COUNT. The resulting query should only show each ward once and with it, only the highest occurring crime type, along with the number of times that that crime occurred in that particular ward. Here is my first query:

```
   SELECT ward, primary_type, COUNT(primary_type) as amt_of_crimes
  
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
    WHERE ward IS NOT NULL AND year = 2022
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

From here, I am unable to correctly filter the query to display only each distinct ward once. I had made a subquery to try and filter each ward with a DISTINCT clause but it didn't work. I'm sure I need to use a subquery here to further filter out each repeating non-distinct value but I can't make it work. I had thought of CASTing from a INT to a STRING value but it didn't help either.

Here is the result from the first query. As you can see, ward #27 appears twice in the first 7 rows, whereas I only want each ward # appearing once.

[image]

Ideally afterward I would ORDER BY the wards in ascending order, but that is not a problem.

I seem to be stuck here, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below.

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT ward, primary_type as crime_type, COUNT(primary_type) as amt_of_crimes
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.chicago_crime.crime`
   WHERE ward IS NOT NULL AND year = 2022
   GROUP BY 1, 2
) QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ward ORDER BY amt_of_crimes DESC) = 1
 ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

**Query results**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jay. This worked perfectly. I realized that QUALIFY would filter the window function according to each n ranked value within the table, i.e 1 = highest value per partition, 2 = second highest per partition, etc.